# How do I play audio with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a short audio track to a game of concentration I'm coding. I want the sound to occur when the user has won the game. How do I go about doing this?
I would really appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933969/sound-effects-in-javascript-html5

Comment: In my game, I play music with an embedded Youtube player.

Comment: What browsers and versions do You want to support?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using something like canvas and you're already depending on the browser supporting HTML5, you can use the `audio` element.

```
var win = new Audio('srcfile.wav');
if(playerWon === true){
    win.play();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Audio in HTML5 is a minefield at the moment, with patchy format support.

We wrote a few blog posts about audio support in HTML5.  This chart shows browser support:
http://www.scirra.com/blog/44/on-html5-audio-formats-aac-and-ogg#chart

Surprisingly, IE doesn't support playback of WAVs.  You should pick audio 2 formats to get coverage on all the platforms.

**Beware using MP3's in games**

It will cost you $2,500 per title in licensing fees if it has more than 5,000 distributions.
http://www.scirra.com/blog/64/why-you-shouldnt-use-mp3-in-your-html5-games

We think the best combination to use is AAC/Ogg to cover all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

I found an [article](http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/9/17/revisiting_html5_audio/) describing [this library](https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-audio-fx) which should fit your needs.

If you don't have sound files yet and want to create them with some fx library then you might want to look at [jsfx](https://github.com/egonelbre/jsfx) which I used in my last [game typdown](https://github.com/TomK32/typedown) (specially these two files are interesting (don't mind the coffeescript, it all compiles to javascript): [sounds](https://github.com/TomK32/typedown/blob/master/game/javascripts/controllers/sounds.js.coffee) and [game controller](https://github.com/TomK32/typedown/blob/master/game/javascripts/controllers/game.js.coffee#L53)

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Audio API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/) is perfect for playing audio in javascript, but currently only Chrome supports it.